# Why should we use setState when we modify some values in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very beginner at React. And now I'm studying about setState() method.

I'm studying with an instruction of tutorial for beginners, but there's something i can't understand.

The topic that the tutorial dealt was making Counter component that displays changing value when we click plus or minus buttons.

The example was like :

```html
function Counter() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

  const onIncrease = () => {
    setNumber(number + 1);
  }

  const onDecrease = () => {
    setNumber(number - 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{number}</h1>
      <button onClick={onIncrease}>+1</button>
      <button onClick={onDecrease}>-1</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And while the learning, i thought this method :

```html
function Counter() {
    let number = 0;
    
    const onIncrease = () => {
        console.log({number});
        number++;
        console.log({number});
    }
    const onDecrease = () => {
        number-=1;
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{number}</h1>
            <button onClick={onIncrease}>+1</button>
            <button onClick={onDecrease}>-1</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

As you may easily recognize, it didn't work.

But I can't understand why it doesn't work properly. It seems to related with why we use setState() as I think.

Thank you for your concern, and I would really appreciate it if you could leave a reply.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: If you're updating your `number` with just `number++;`, then there is no way for React to know that the `number` changed (there isn't anything that allows React to "watch" this variable for changes), and so it won't know that it needs to re-render. Using `setState()` notifies React that your state has been modified, and also enables React to check if the state has changed from the previous render which if it has, it will re-render your component with the new state value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reassigning a variable, by itself, (almost) never has any side effects - this is true not only in React, but in all JavaScript as well. You need to tell React in a way that it understands that a value has changed *and that the component needs to re-render as a result* - thus the need for a function call (`setNumber`).

With React's paradigm, the way a component renders should be determinable completely from that component's *state* (and props), for the most part. React can keep track of changes to state and props easily - it can't (nothing in JavaScript can) keep track of *reassigned variables* automatically.

Calling a state setter like `setNumber` tells React to:

1. Update React's internal state data for this component
2. Re-render the component

If you just reassign a variable, like `number++`, neither of those can be accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

This all ties into the React lifecycle.  When you have an MV* library, the idea is that there is a data model wired to a UI, and when you update your data model the library will do the work to update your UI accordingly.  In order for the library to update the UI, it critically *must know that the data model has changed*.  If you simply update the values in plain JS, the library has no easy or performant way of knowing that the data model has changed.  For this reason, the library provides its own methods for updating the data model-- if you only update the data model with these methods, then the library will know that they data model has changed and that a update to the UI must be scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

### **You can imagine like this**

Reactjs function component is also a normal function, every renders the `function` get invoked all over again.

And when you declare `let number = 0;` as a local variable in a normal function, `does it keep the last value from the last invoke?` Obviously not,

**Then React works the same way.**

---

So, In order to persist your `local variable` within invokes, you will need to have a way to store them outside of your function, `useState` or `useRef` are two of them.